# How to filter in AWS Congito with multiple filter conditions in ListUsersCommand in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, amazon-cognito, aws-sdk-js

We want to filter out the user list with multiple filter conditions, like on `email and status` in the node.js. Tried below filter condition but it did't work.

Code snippet of node.js

```
const client = new CognitoIdentityProviderClient(<config>);
const inputForFetchUserList = {
  Filter: `'email'= 'abc@gmail.com' and 'cognito:user_status' = 'FORCE_CHANGE_PASSWORD'`,
  UserPoolId: <UserPoolId>, //required
  Limit: 5,
};
const commandForFetchUserList = new ListUsersCommand(inputForFetchUserList);
const cognitoListUsersResponse = await client.send(commandForFetchUserList);
```

Comment: Try this instead: `email= 'abc@gmail.com' and cognito:user_status = 'FORCE_CHANGE_PASSWORD'`

Comment: Above filter  is not working

Answer (score 0):

```js
const { CognitoIdentityProviderClient, ListUsersCommand } = require('@aws-sdk/client-cognito-identity-provider');

async function listUsersWithFilter() {
    const client = new CognitoIdentityProviderClient({ region: 'your-region' }); // Replace 'your-region' with the appropriate AWS region

    // Define your filter conditions
    const filters = [
        { Name: 'email', Value: 'user@example.com' },
        { Name: 'custom:customAttribute', Value: 'customValue' }
        // Add more filter conditions as needed
    ];

    // Set up the ListUsersCommand with the Filters parameter
    const listUsersCommand = new ListUsersCommand({
        UserPoolId: 'your-user-pool-id', // Replace 'your-user-pool-id' with your actual User Pool ID
        Filter: filters
    });

    try {
        // Execute the command
        const response = await client.send(listUsersCommand);

        // Output the list of users
        console.log('Users:', response.Users);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error listing users:', error);
    }
}

// Call the function to list users with filters
listUsersWithFilter();
```

Comment: Is this just copy paste? Can you please provide an explanation for what OP should be looking at here with references to documentation? This doesn't actually answer the question and is just sample code.